# Going from a top-down to a bottom-up algorithm (DP)

Tags: ruby, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have created this algorithm to compute the longest palindrome subsequence (word that is the same when mirrors, ie "aba", "racecar"), and have done so using a recursive top-down approach. I know that it's possible to turn these into iterative algorithms working from the bottom-up, but I am having trouble seeing how this could be accoplished

My code

```
def palindrome(string, r = {})
    return 1 if string.length == 1
    return 2 if string[0] == string[1] and string.length == 2
    return r[string] if r.include?(string)
    n = string.length
    if string[0] == string[n-1]     
        r[string] = palindrome(string[1..n-2],r) + 2
    else
        r[string] = [palindrome(string[0..n-2],r), palindrome(string[1..n-1],r)].max
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1. When you use negative numbers when fetching an item from an array, the array counts the elements *from the end*, so you don't have to keep the `n` variable

   ```
   if string[0] == string[-1] # <= same as string[n-1]
     r[string] = palindrome(string[1..-2],r) + 2 # <= same as string[1..n-2]
   ```
2. I don't know how performant this is, but here is a top-down suggestion:

   ```
   def palindrome(string)
     chars = string.chars
     chars.length.downto(1).find do |length|
       chars.each_cons(length).any? { |cons| cons == cons.reverse }
     end
   end
   ```